# Azure ServiceBus wildcard subscription

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

I have two sets of agents running on a group of computers - they post to two services bus topics that were created on the azure portal:

- announce/awoga-corp
- announce/company-first

I then have a server that needs to listen to any of these agents, from a namespace perspective `announce/*`

I have gone to create a subscription on my server via the azure portal, however i can only create a subscription to a specific topic i.e. `announce/awoga-corp` OR `announce/company-first`.

How can I with Azure subscrbe to receive all messages on master path (i.e `announce/*`) via  single call with `receiver.ReceiveMessageAsync(cancellationToken: stoppingToken)`?

Sorry if some terminology is off, I am coming from an MQTT background.

[image: subscription]

Comment: Is `announce` a Topic and `awoga-corp` & `company-first` Subscriptions in that Topic  in your Azure Service Bus Namespace?

Comment: Ahhhh. No, I created two topics. I think I may see the issue here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Azure Service Bus, a message must always be sent to a Topic. AFAIK, there is no concept of wildcard topic.

You could create a single Topic (let's call it `announce`) and create two Subscriptions inside it (let's call them `awoga-corp` and `company-first`). Your agent would send the messages to the Topic and you can specify Filtering rules to send messages to these individual Subscriptions.

If you wish to process all messages together, then all you would need to do is create a 3rd Subscription and set a Filtering rule so that all messages are also sent to this 3rd Subscription.

You can then configure your receiver to receive messages from this 3rd Subscription only.